# Chrome Extension's persistent cookies not expiring correctly?

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome-extension

#### Summary:

Basically, I'm using a background page to listen to events, such as: onStartup, onInstalled and cookies.onChanged to decide which page should be displayed to the user when the browserAction is clicked. My question regards the latter and how it is triggered.

---

#### Code sample:

```
chrome.cookies.onChanged.addListener(function(info){
    if(info.cookie.name === "dummycookie"){
        /*  Possibilities of info.cause (as described in the docs):
        *       evicted
        *       expired
        *       explicit (it's used when setting or removing a cookie)
        *       expired_overwrite
        *       overwrite
        */
        if(info.cause == "overwrite" || (info.cause == "explicit" && !info.removed)){
            // Cookie was set (explicit or overwrite)
            chrome.browserAction.setPopup({ popup: "dummy1.html" });
        }
        else{
            // Cookie was removed (evicted, expired or expired_overwrite)
            chrome.browserAction.setPopup({ popup: "dummy2.html" });
        }
    }
});
```

---

The thing is, although the code above handles explicit calls just fine (cookies.set & cookies.get), it doesn't seem to trigger when a cookie life-span expires..

From the debugging sessions I conducted, the code is only triggered when a explicit call is made after the cookie's expected expiration date.

E.g. if I make a call like cookies.getAll() after the supposed expiration time, the browser realizes that the cookie has expired and only then the event is triggered.

Did I miss anything ? Can anyone please enlighten me if I'm misusing the cookies API or if I misunderstood the mechanic behind it ?

Any help is greatly appreciated !

Best regards,

Comment: I suggest to change your logic. Instead of pasively listening to cookie events, actively query the state of the cookie when the popup is opened. This will not only work around your bug, but it is also less resource-intensive.

Comment: @RobW Thank you for leaving a comment, I appreciate it since this question hasn't gotten much attention.. Anyways, I'm not sure if I understood what you suggested correctly, but if I query the state of the cookie once the popup is requested and only then change the HTML that should be displayed, I'm going to create a bad user experience, because he will have to click twice the browser action to actually upate the popup. (The first will set the popup's html and the second to actually get a valid cookie state and then get the page to be displayed correctly).

Comment: Why not? `chrome.cookies.get({url: 'http://example.com/', name: 'dummycookie'}, function(cookies) { /* now do whatever you want */ });`

Comment: I accidentaly pressed enter before finishing my response, could you read it again ? I'm not sure I made myself clear enough though..

Comment: What makes you think that the user has to click twice? You can use a single HTML page, and use `chrome.cookies.get` within the popup page to get the cookie and update the document based on the result.

Comment: Ok, I see your point now. That would indeed probably work, and since it maintains the original architecture I had planned, I guess we can call this an answer :) Could you write an answer to the question so that I can accept it ?

Comment: Could you edit your question such that the title is closer to what you want? At the moment if others look for a reason why persistent cookies are not expiring, then they'd be disappointed if they read my answer.

Comment: But still, in theory what I did should work, right ? Or did I misunderstand the mechanics behind it? I mean, the listener on "cookies.onChanged" should have captured the cookie's state change to expired, shouldn't it ?

Comment: Also, as to being less resource-intensive, I'm not sure about that, because I was using a non persistent background page, so that it should only become active when an event it was listening to triggered.

Comment: In theory, yes, your code should have worked. I haven't tried to confirm your bug though for the lack of time. Cookies are updated a lot, while users are probably not opening the popup very often, so my suggestion is indeed less resource-intensive.

Comment: Yes, I could update the title, but I'm not sure that's the right thing to do, because I've only now realized the question has a bounty on it, so although your answer does provide a work-around to my problem, it still doesn't answer the original question, which is the reason @Xan offered the bounty.. What should we do about it ? I'm not such an avid user of stackoverflow, so I'm not sure what would be the right procedure in this situation..

Comment: I found the question interesting enough as-is, e.g. a confirmation that it is a bug (with a link to the issue report) or an error found in your code (if any) would be a good answer. But then again, I think @RobW's workaround answer would also fit.

Comment: So, @RobW can you post your answer ? I think we should keep the title as it is and have your answer as a work-around to what I was looking for. In addition to that, I'll report this behavior as a possible bug and complement your answer once I have a valid return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For rare actions such as opening the [browser action popup](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction), you'd better actively [query](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies#method-get) the cookies API for the latest state of the relevant cookie, instead of listening for cookie changes via the [`chrome.cookies.onChanged`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies#event-onChanged), because:

1. If your observed bug is real, then this will work around it.
2. Since the popup is not opened very often, it's quite a waste of resources to keep a background/event page alive merely to get notified of cookie changes, especially given the alternative method presented in this answer.

Example (popup.js, requires [activeTab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab) and cookies permission):

```js
// Example: Get the value of the _gaq cookie for the top-level frame of the
// current tab.
chrome.tabs.query({
    active: true,
    currentWindow: true
}, function(tabs) {
    // Need activeTab permission to read url, e.g. http://example.com/home
    var url = tabs[0].url;
    chrome.cookies.get({
        url: url,
        name: '_gaq'
    }, function(cookie) {
        // TODO: Do something with cookie, e.g. by updating the view (via DOM).
    });
});
```

Comment: Now we only need to wait for an issue report number, OP promised to file one.

Comment: @Xan I've been rather busy with work, but I'll try to file this behavior today and get back to you guys with the response / issue tracking number.